# How to translate default Cookie Restriction Mode message in Magento 2.3.2?

Tags: magento, translation, magento2

I am trying to transalte the defualt Cookie Restriction Mode Message in Magento 2.3.2. I've tried, adding the whole message in my bg_BG.csv file in my custom child theme where all my other translations are located but the new translation is not applied. I've tried searching for a Block but I do not have one. Is there something which I am not doing correctly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are doing wrong is that you should not add the whole message at once in your custom bg_BG.csv file. If you check the Cookie message itself is split in two parts:

1st:

> We use cookies to make your experience better.

2nd:

> To comply with the new e-Privacy directive, we need to ask for your consent to set the cookies.

You have to translate both the messages separately. After that deploy static content and clean cache.